# Do I have to scuff semi-gloss paint with sandpaper before second coat?

Tags: painting, trim, sanding

I applied one coat of semi-gloss paint over a week ago and am finally getting around to the second coat.

There is over 80 feet of crown molding and trim to be painted and it's not a basic pattern.

Is scuffing it with sandpaper the only option for good adhesion?

The paint is Sherwin Williams Promar 200 if it matters. The rear of the paint can is smeared with paint so I cannot read the instructions.

[image]

Comment: Can's got paint on it? https://www.sherwin-williams.com/painting-contractors/products/promar-200-zero-voc-interior-latex

Answer (score 5):

[The literature](https://www.sherwin-williams.com/document/PDS/en/035777433768/) from the [product page](https://www.sherwin-williams.com/painting-contractors/products/promar-200-zero-voc-interior-latex) lists a minimum recoat time (temp- and humidity-dependent). It doesn't mention a *maximum* time or any caveats with respect to recoat.

> Drying Time, @ 77°F, 50% RH
> Touch: 1 Hour
> Recoat: 4 Hours

This implies that no further prep is necessary to recoat. In my experience, interior house paint almost never requires sanding between coats. I wouldn't expect it to be generally necessary with semi-gloss paints anyway.

Comment: I agree the only surfaces I sand or skuff is poly paint I just recoat.